# angular 2 on table row click, fill input form

Tags: angular

everyone. I'm new to Angular 2, so sorry if i've made any mistakes. I'm trying to make a table such that when the user clicks on the table row, the data inside that row transfers to an input form which is filled with the row data. In this form, the user can edit the row clicked. while editing, the exact same table row the user clicked should auto-update with every keystroke or select option. I'm stuck on the form transfer part. Here's my code (all in one component):

```
<button (click)="add()">Create</button>
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Title</th>
 <th>Priority</th>
 <th>Status</th>
 <th>Due Date</th>
 <th>Date Created</th>
 <th>Date Modified</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks; let index=index" (click)="checking()">
 <td>{{tasks[index].Title}}</td>
 <td>{{tasks[index].Priority}}</td>
 <td>{{tasks[index].Status}}</td>
 <td>{{tasks[index].Due_Date}}</td>
 <td>{{objDate | date:'short'}}</td>
 <td>{{tasks[index].Date_Modified}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here is the task details form:

```
<div style="text-align: left">
Title:
  <div><textarea style="width: 290px" [(ngModel)]="tasks[0].Title"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div style="text-align: left">
Description:
  <div><textarea style="width: 290px"></textarea></div>
</div>
<br />
<div style="float: left">
Priority:
<select>
  <option selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option>Normal</option>
  <option>Major</option>
  <option>Critical</option>
</select>
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
Status:
<select>
  <option selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option>ToDo</option>
  <option>In Progress</option>
  <option>Done</option>
</select>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div>
Due Date (mm/dd/yyyy):
</div>
<br />
<div>
Parent:
<select style="width: 250px">
  <option selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option>Task 1</option>
  <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Task 1.1</option>
  <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Task 1.2</option>
  <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Task 1.2.1</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me? I've been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is doing some two-way data binding with ngModel. You'll need to import FormsModule in your module. And then in your component you could do something like this (I just simplified your code into something really simple to show the concept):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Second</th>
      <th>Third</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let task of tasks; let index=index" (click)="checking(index)">
      <td>{{task.first}}</td>
      <td>{{task.second}}</td>
      <td>{{task.third}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div>
    <form ngForm>
      <label for="first">First:</label>
      <input
        id="first"
        name="first"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedTask.first">
      <label for="second">Second:</label>
      <input
        id="second"
        name="second"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedTask.second">
      <label for="third">Third: </label>
      <select
        name="third"
        id="third"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedTask.third">
        <option selected>Select</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedTask = {
    first: '',
    second: '',
    third: '',
  };

  tasks = [
    {
      first: 'Hi',
      second: 'This is my greeting',
      third: 'A'
    },
    {
      first: 'Bonjour',
      second: 'From france',
      third: 'C'
    },
    {
      first: 'Hi',
      second: 'Another greeting',
      third: 'C'
    }
  ];

  checking(index) {
    this.selectedTask = this.tasks[index];
  }
}
```